# "crypto failure" error when running various commands

Tags: openssl, ssl, dig, nslookup

I'm finding that a few commands (for now `dig` and `nslookup`) that fail no matter what with the following output:

```
19-Jan-2016 15:01:50.219 ENGINE_by_id failed (crypto failure)
19-Jan-2016 15:01:50.219 error:2606A074:engine routines:ENGINE_by_id:no such engine:eng_list.c:389:id=gost
dig: dst_lib_init: crypto failure
```

Even stuff like `dig -h` results in this, so I guess this happens before the actual command execution starts

I remember these commands used to work, but they're not something I used very often, so I can't exactly pinpoint the origin

I can, however, say that I have messed with ssl options recently. Particularly, I was having problems handling GPG keys, and had to run `export OPENSSL_CONF=/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf` in order to make it work
I also found [this issue](https://github.com/drwetter/testssl.sh/issues/134), which seems to be similar. But that project has nothing to do with what I'm doing, and their solution (unsetting OPENSSL_CONF) did not work for me

**EDIT**:
I'm running Arch Linux.
The only change I did regarding OpenSSL configurations was running `export OPENSSL_CONF=/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf` which I needed to use `gpg`, but I already tried unsetting that

Running `unset OPENSSL_CONF; dig -h` results in the same output

Comment: It might help to give more information, i.e. which OS and what changes you made to your ssl options.  Can you provide the output of ldd /usr/bin/dig?  Also, what happens if you do unset OPENSSL_CONF; dig -h

Comment: This sounds like a version mismatch between the libssl library dig was compiled against and the version that's actually installed. Try `strace -ffF -s200 dig 2>&1 | fgrep gost`; it should try to load it from somewhere like `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/openssl-1.0.2/engines/libgost.so` but it's probably not there.

Comment: @AndrásKorn that strace just gave me a similar output `[pid  5688] write(2, "25-Jan-2016 09:19:18.075 error:2606A074:engine routines:ENGINE_by_id:no such engine:eng_list.c:389:id=gost\n", 10725-Jan-2016 09:19:18.075 error:2606A074:engine routines:ENGINE_by_id:no such engine:eng_list.c:389:id=gost`

I looked for a `libgost.so` and I found it in both `/usr/lib/engines/libgost.so` and `/usr/lib32/engines/libgost.so`.

@vik I'll update the post with the info you requested

Comment: Well, this is what it's supposed to print: `[pid 15583] open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openssl-1.0.2/engines/libgost.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 6` -- so for some reason it doesn't even try to load the library on your system. Just out of curiosity, what happens if you do `LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/engines/libgost.so dig`?

Comment: @AndrásKorn I get the exact same error message :(

Comment: OK, this reinforces my impression that the problem is a version mismatch. I'm not familiar with Arch Linux... Are your `dnsutils` and `libssl*` packages up to date? Were they all installed by the package manager or did you compile, for example, libssl yourself?

Comment: Everything is up to date (updated again today), everything is managed by my package mananger, although I'm using some AUR packages, which are user-contributed repositories. It wouldn't be the first time someone introduces a version mismatch or incompatiblity there, but that's usually solved by updating again a couple of days later. And the more important stuff such as libssl is still managed by the official packages

Comment: Can you find libgost.so on your system anywhere?  When you find it try Andras' suggestion with LD_PRELOAD.  Please post the output of ldd /usr/bin/dig and ldd /usr/bin/openssl as well.

Comment: It sounds like one of the AUR packages messed up your openssl install.  Maybe pacman -Ql <package> and see if any of them are messing with openssl?  Also, do you get the same error if you run openssl list-message-digest-algorithms?

Comment: @Naps62, pls show us `ldd $( which dig)` as @vik mentions. Additionally I request `pacman -Qo /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf`

Comment: @KWubbufetowicz the "pacman -Qo" command tells me `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf is owned by openssl 1.0.2.e-1`. The `ldd` output is here: http://pastebin.com/bjpy1DGm. 

@vik I'm not sure what you want me to try out with `pacman -Ql`. As for the `list-message-digest-algorithms`, it runs fine, although the output makes no mention of gost (i'm not sure if it was suposed to)

Comment: @Naps62, huh see your ldd input : `        libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /opt/toggldesktop/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f58ff032000)`. This is most probably the cause of your problem. This should normally lead to openssl libs located somewhere in /lib dir. Inspect file /etc/ld.so.conf and /etc/ld.so.cond.d dir. Remove path to /opt/toggldesktop/lib if found. Run `ldconfig -v 2>&1 | grep crypto`, now path should point to correct openssl lib. Try running dig afterwards.

Comment: @KWubbufetowicz wow. Didn't notice that. I was unable to find any reference to toggldesktop in `ld.so.conf` or `ld.so.conf.d`, but I simply uninstalled the `toggl-bin` package and everything seems to work now!

So I guess this is an issue with either toggl, or the package that installs it?

Finally, can you provide an answer so I can accept it (that's the only way for you to receive the bounty I think?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run : 
`ldd $( which dig) | grep crypto`, this will show you which crypto lib you're using at the moment. If this is different than expected one (usually openssl) you have few options :

1. Remove the lib which interferes
2. Modify LDD_LIBARY_PATH env variable, and point to the openssl lib location
3. Fix the problem by removing unwanted library' location from /etc/ld.so.conf and /etc/ld.so.cond.d/* files. Running `ldconfig` afterwards. Warning : this will most probably break application using it.